# how to clear cache in SharePoint designer Site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have try to open SharePoint 2013 site from SharePoint designer 2013 but its not working.

**How can I clear SharePoint Site cache?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**For clear SharePoint designer site cache follow the below steps.**

1. Close SharePoint Desginer2013.
2. Delete everything from **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache**.
3. Delete everything from **%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache**.
4. Now open your SharePoint site from SPD it will definitely work.

Answer (score 1):

Press window+R and remove the cache from four places

1. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
2. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
3. %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
4. %APPDATA%\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer

For more info, please refer [SharePoint designer error](http://www.techrobbers.com/2019/10/how-to-clear-sharepoint-designer-cache.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment on the answer above, point 3 should be "%APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache" I think